# How do I know the last unselected option from a multiselect dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, listbox, multi-select

I have a multi select Listbox

```
<div id="multiselectList">
  <select>
    <option value="option1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Val 2</option>
    <option value="option5">Val 3</option>
  </select>
```

Suppose all the options are selected initially. Now I unselect option2 from multi select list. How can I know which option is currently unselected by the user. I used below code but it was giving me all the unselected values.

```
var unselectedValue = $("#multiselectList").find('option:not(:selected)');
```

Can anyone help me in finding the solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `$("#multiselectList").find('option:not(:selected)').last()` maybe?

Comment: It is always giving option5 as output. But I need to check the latest unselected option.

Comment: *I used below code* - when exactly do you use this code? When the page first loads?

Comment: Please clarify: do you mean the last as in 1,2,3 - 3=last or do you mean the most-recent, as in the previous, so I select 3,2,1 - "last selected was 1"?

Comment: the most recent unchecked option

Comment: Then you'd need to store how it was before and compare with how it is now

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery *last()* for it

https://api.jquery.com/last/

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', () => {

  var unselectedValue = $("#multiselectList").find('option:not(:selected)').last();
  console.log(unselectedValue.val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiselectList">
  <select multiple>
    <option value="option1" selected>Val 1</option>
    <option value="option2" selected>Val 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="option5" selected>Val 5</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: It is always giving option5 as output.

Comment: Yes because it is the last option when the site is loaded, I can update it to put it inside a function which gets called when the value changes

Comment: When you now select the last option it will outputs element4 as you can see in the snippet above

Comment: I've also made it a multiselect as in the question with opt5 pre-selected, so that it outputs option4 on start

Answer (score 0):

**Try Using**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sel").on("click", function(event) {
    if(!event.originalEvent.srcElement.selected) {
      console.log($(event.originalEvent.srcElement).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiselectList">
  <select id="sel" multiple>
    <option value="option1" selected>Val 1</option>
    <option value="option2" selected>Val 2</option>
    <option value="option3" selected>Val 3</option>
    <option value="option4" selected>Val 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Val 5</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using**

```js
// save array to compare in function check
let lastSelected = [];

// set last selected value on document ready
$(document).ready(() => {
  lastSelected = $('select option:not(:selected)')
    .map((i, el) => el.value)
    .get();
});

$('select').on('change', () => {
  const currentSelected = $('select option:not(:selected)')
    .map((i, el) => el.value)
    .get();

  // compare to get recently selected
  const selected = lastSelected.filter(
    (val) => !currentSelected.includes(val)
  );

  // compare to get recently unselected
  const unselected = currentSelected.filter(
    (val) => !lastSelected.includes(val)
  );

  recentChanges(selected, unselected);

  // update last selected
  lastSelected = currentSelected;
});

// recentChanges event
function recentChanges(selected, unselected) {
  console.log(
    (selected.length > 0 ? selected : 'nothing') + ' is selected'
  );
  console.log(
    (unselected.length > 0 ? unselected : 'nothing') + ' is unselected'
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select multiple>
  <option value="option1" selected>Val 1</option>
  <option value="option2" selected>Val 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Val 3</option>
  <option value="option4">Val 4</option>
  <option value="option5" selected>Val 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I know which option is currently unselected by the user.

```js
// This is the selected value on page load
let selected = $("#multiselectList option:selected").text()

// On change event
$("#multiselectList select").on("change", function(){

  // Keep the previous selection
  let prevSelection = selected

  // Get the new one
  selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  
  // Results
  console.log(`${prevSelection} was deselected and ${selected} was selected.`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiselectList">
  <select>
    <option value="option1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="option3" selected>Val 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Val 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Val 5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```